# Fired a shot into the air/ceiling

Tags: word-choice

The armed bank robbers strode into the bank and fired a shot into the air/ceiling.

If inside, could "into the air" be used or should I go with "into the ceiling" or something else?

Comment: You can say *a warning shot*.

Comment: “into the air” means the bullets won’t hit *anything* but air, which seems rather unlikely indoors.

Comment: Bullets fired into the air don't just vanish; they fall somewhere, and can injure or kill, as people attending weddings or other celebrations (or those some distance away) in certain countries painfully discover. [The dangers of celebratory gunfire](https://blogs.bcm.edu/2019/12/31/what-goes-up-must-come-down-the-dangers-of-celebratory-gunfire/)